# Why does my code give the error, "NameError: name 'r' is not defined" only when any of the available resources isn't enough to make coffee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I am new to python and the code below is supposed to simulate a coffee machine. The code works well, but when any of the available resources is insufficient to make a new cup of coffee, it produces a name error. I have tried storing resources[r] in the function to a variable, then include the variable in the condition statements by using the **global** keyword, but the issue persists. The goal is to inform the user when any of the resources is not enough to prepare the order.

```
    #Coffee ingredients and costs    
        MENU = {
            "espresso": {
                "ingredients": {
                    "water": 50,
                    "coffee": 18,
        
                },
                "cost": 1.5,
            },
            "latte": {
                "ingredients": {
                    "water": 200,
                    "milk": 150,
                    "coffee": 24,
                },
                "cost": 2.5,
            },
            "cappuccino": {
                "ingredients": {
                    "water": 250,
                    "milk": 100,
                    "coffee": 24,
                },
                "cost": 3.0,
            }
        }
        #Coffee machine resources
        resources = {
            "water": 300,
            "milk": 200,
            "coffee": 100,
            "money": 0
        }
        
        #Loop through MENU to get the quantities of necessary ingredients to make a particular type of coffee
        for items in MENU:
            print(items)
            water = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['water'])
            coffee = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
            if items != 'espresso':
                milk = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['milk'])
        
        #Function that loops through the resources dictionary to provide the current quantities of available resources
        def report():
            for r in resources:
                if r.lower() == "water":
                    print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"ml")
                if r.lower() == "milk":
                    print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"ml")
                if r.lower() == "coffee":
                    print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"g")
                if r.lower() == "money":
                    print(f'{r}: ${resources[r]}')
            return resources[r];
        
        global r
        power = True
        while power:
            print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
            pennies = int(input("How many pennies did you insert?: "))
            nickles = int(input("How many nickles did you insert?: "))
            dimes = int(input("How many dimes did you insert?: "))
            quarters = int(input("How many quarters did you insert?: "))
            coinValue = (0.01*pennies)+(0.05*nickles)+(0.10*dimes)+(0.25*quarters)
            resources['money'] = resources['money']+coinValue
            coffeeChoice = input("What would you like? Espresso, Latte or Cappuccino?").lower()

            if coffeeChoice == "report":

                report()
            if coffeeChoice == "espresso" and ((resources['water'] < 50) or (resources['coffee'] < 18)):
                if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
                if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
            elif coffeeChoice == "espresso" and ((resources['water'] >= 50) and (resources['coffee'] >= 18)):
                resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['espresso'])['ingredients'])['water'])
                resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['espresso'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
                resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['espresso'])['cost']))
                if resources['money'] > 0:
                    resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
                    print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
                print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
                resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']
            
if coffeeChoice == "latte" and ((resources['water'] < 200) or (resources['coffee'] < 24) or (resources['milk'] < 150)):
                if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
                if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
                if r.lower() == "milk" and milk > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough milk.")
            elif coffeeChoice == "latte" and ((resources['water'] >= 200) and (resources['coffee'] >= 24) and (resources['milk'] >= 150)):
                resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['water'])
                resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
                resources['milk'] = resources['milk'] - (((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['milk'])
                resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['latte'])['cost']))
                if resources['money'] > 0:
                    resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
                    print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
                print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
                resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']
            
if coffeeChoice == "cappuccino" and ((resources['water'] < 250) or (resources['coffee'] < 24) or (resources['milk'] < 100)):
                if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
                if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
                if r.lower() == "milk" and milk > resources[r]:
                    print("Sorry, there is not enough milk.")
                print("Insufficient resources")
            elif coffeeChoice == "cappuccino" and ((resources['water'] >= 250) and (resources['coffee'] >= 24) and (resources['milk'] >= 100)):
                resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['water'])
                print(f"{resources['water']}")
                resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
                resources['milk'] = resources['milk'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['milk'])
                resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['cost']))
                if resources['money'] > 0:
                    resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
                    print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
                print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
                resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']
            report()
            powerOff = input("Do you want to turn off the machine?: Y or N ").lower()
            if powerOff == 'y':
                power = False
```

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] after you have tried some debugging. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think you jumped to conclusion by saying I never debugged the code. FYI, the code was written on Pycharm, and at first it caught the error. However, when I added the **global** keyword, the error indicator (i.e., red squiggly line) dissappeared. From one perspective, it makes sense because 'r' in the for loop acts as a variable, and to be able to access a variable outside a function the **global** keyword is used.

Answer (score 0):

the issue as you have gathered from the error is that you try to use a variable `r` prior to that variable being assigned a value. I have highlighted this in your code. If you like I can add some fixes.

```
#Coffee ingredients and costs
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,

        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

#Coffee machine resources
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money": 0
}

## ---------------------------------------------------
# Loop through MENU to get the quantities of necessary ingredients to make a particular type of coffee
## ---------------------------------------------------
## JonSG: This is not doing what you think it does.
## JonSG: The result of this is that water = 250 as only the last item's ingredients are set.
## JonSG: You probably don't need/want this code block
## ---------------------------------------------------
for items in MENU:
    print(items)
    water = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['water'])
    coffee = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
    if items != 'espresso':
        milk = (((MENU[items])['ingredients'])['milk'])
## ---------------------------------------------------

## ---------------------------------------------------
# Function that loops through the resources dictionary to provide the current quantities of available resources
## ---------------------------------------------------
## JonSG: You might want to think about passing resources into this function
## JonSG: so that is is not reliant on a global.
## JonSG: Additionally "r" is only meaningful inside the for loop so your return is going to error
## JonSG: You never assign a variable based on a call to report so the return can likely just be removed.
## ---------------------------------------------------
def report():
    for r in resources:
        if r.lower() == "water":
            print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"ml")
        if r.lower() == "milk":
            print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"ml")
        if r.lower() == "coffee":
            print(f'{r}: {resources[r]}'+"g")
        if r.lower() == "money":
            print(f'{r}: ${resources[r]}')

    ## JonSG: probably don't need/want this
    return resources[r];
## ---------------------------------------------------

global r
power = True

while power:
    print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
    pennies = int(input("How many pennies did you insert?: "))
    nickles = int(input("How many nickles did you insert?: "))
    dimes = int(input("How many dimes did you insert?: "))
    quarters = int(input("How many quarters did you insert?: "))
    coinValue = (0.01*pennies)+(0.05*nickles)+(0.10*dimes)+(0.25*quarters)
    resources['money'] = resources['money']+coinValue
    coffeeChoice = input("What would you like? Espresso, Latte or Cappuccino?").lower()

    if coffeeChoice == "report":
        report()

    if coffeeChoice == "espresso" and ((resources['water'] < 50) or (resources['coffee'] < 18)):
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        ## At this point "r" has not been assigned a value so this is going to error out
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
        if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
        ## ---------------------------------------------------

    elif coffeeChoice == "espresso" and ((resources['water'] >= 50) and (resources['coffee'] >= 18)):
        resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['espresso'])['ingredients'])['water'])
        resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['espresso'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
        resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['espresso'])['cost']))
        if resources['money'] > 0:
            resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
            print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
        print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
        resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']

    if coffeeChoice == "latte" and ((resources['water'] < 200) or (resources['coffee'] < 24) or (resources['milk'] < 150)):
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        ## At this point "r" has not been assigned a value so this is going to error out
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
        if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
        if r.lower() == "milk" and milk > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough milk.")
        ## ---------------------------------------------------

    elif coffeeChoice == "latte" and ((resources['water'] >= 200) and (resources['coffee'] >= 24) and (resources['milk'] >= 150)):
        resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['water'])
        resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
        resources['milk'] = resources['milk'] - (((MENU['latte'])['ingredients'])['milk'])
        resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['latte'])['cost']))
        if resources['money'] > 0:
            resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
            print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
        print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
        resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']

    if coffeeChoice == "cappuccino" and ((resources['water'] < 250) or (resources['coffee'] < 24) or (resources['milk'] < 100)):
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        ## At this point "r" has not been assigned a value so this is going to error out
        ## ---------------------------------------------------
        if r.lower() == "water" and water > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough water.")
        if r.lower() == "coffee" and coffee > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough coffee.")
        if r.lower() == "milk" and milk > resources[r]:
            print("Sorry, there is not enough milk.")
        print("Insufficient resources")
        ## ---------------------------------------------------

    elif coffeeChoice == "cappuccino" and ((resources['water'] >= 250) and (resources['coffee'] >= 24) and (resources['milk'] >= 100)):
        resources['water'] = resources['water']-(((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['water'])
        print(f"{resources['water']}")
        resources['coffee'] = resources['coffee'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['coffee'])
        resources['milk'] = resources['milk'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['ingredients'])['milk'])
        resources['money'] = resources['money'] - (((MENU['cappuccino'])['cost']))
        if resources['money'] > 0:
            resources['money'] = round(resources['money'], 2)
            print(f"Here is ${resources['money']} in change. ")
        print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}. Enjoy!")
        resources['money'] = resources['money']-resources['money']

    report()

    powerOff = input("Do you want to turn off the machine?: Y or N ").lower()
    if powerOff == 'y':
        power = False
```

Here is some ideas to get you going again:

```
## ---------------------------------------------------
#Coffee ingredients and costs
## ---------------------------------------------------
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {"water": 50, "coffee": 18},
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {"water": 200, "milk": 150, "coffee": 24},
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {"water": 250, "milk": 100, "coffee": 24},
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}
## ---------------------------------------------------

## ---------------------------------------------------
## Coffee machine resources
## Let's add in a little more data to make things easier later
## ---------------------------------------------------
resources = {
    "water": {"quantity": 300, "unit_prefix": "", "unit_postfix": "ml"},
    "milk": {"quantity": 200, "unit_prefix": "", "unit_postfix": "ml"},
    "coffee": {"quantity": 100, "unit_prefix": "", "unit_postfix": "g"},
    "money": {"quantity": 0, "unit_prefix": "$", "unit_postfix": ""}
}
## ---------------------------------------------------

## ---------------------------------------------------
## Report on resources
## ---------------------------------------------------
def report(resources):
    print("Resources Remaining:")
    for key, value in resources.items():
        print("\t%s: %s%s%s" % (key, value.get("unit_prefix"), value.get("quantity"), value.get("unit_postfix")))
## ---------------------------------------------------

## ---------------------------------------------------
## Refund the user's remaining credit
## ---------------------------------------------------
def refund(resources):
    print("Here is $%s in change." % resources['money']["quantity"])
    resources['money']["quantity"] = 0
## ---------------------------------------------------

while True:
    print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
    print("You have credit of $%s" % resources["money"]["quantity"])

    pennies = int(input("How many pennies did you insert?: "))
    nickles = int(input("How many nickles did you insert?: "))
    dimes = int(input("How many dimes did you insert?: "))
    quarters = int(input("How many quarters did you insert?: "))

    coinValue = (0.01 * pennies) + (0.05 * nickles) + (0.10 * dimes) + (0.25 * quarters)
    resources['money']["quantity"] += coinValue

    coffeeChoice = input("Would you like? Espresso, Latte, Cappuccino, or Refund? ").lower()

    if coffeeChoice == "report":
        report(resources)
        continue

    if coffeeChoice == "refund":
        refund(resources)
        continue

    product_requested = MENU.get(coffeeChoice)

    if not product_requested:
        print(f"I do not have {coffeeChoice}.")
        continue

    if resources["money"]["quantity"] < product_requested["cost"]:
        print(f"Please insert more money to purchase {coffeeChoice}.")
        continue

    for ingredient, required_quantity in product_requested["ingredients"].items():
        # make sure we have enough stuff to make the request
        if required_quantity > resources[ingredient]["quantity"]:
            print(f"There is not enough {ingredient} to make {coffeeChoice}.")
            # a break here will stop the "for else" from happening
            break
    else:
        # everything seems go so let us vend
        resources["money"]["quantity"] -= product_requested["cost"]
        for ingredient, required_quantity in product_requested["ingredients"].items():
            resources[ingredient]["quantity"] -= required_quantity

        print(f"Here is your {coffeeChoice}.")
        if resources['money']["quantity"] > 0:
            refund(resources)

    if input("Do you want to turn off the machine?: Y or N ").lower() == "y":
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; I really appreciate. For some reason Pycharm didn't catch this, but replit did. On the other hand, the values from the iterations are stored in 'r'. Isn't that technically the same as defining the variable?

Please I could use your help with fixing the code.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a more efficient way of accomplishing the simulation. I have to get familiar with the keywords you used.